# How to make element always up the closing tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here's the snippet

```js
function send(){
  var message = document.getElementById('input').value;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += `<p>${message}</p>`;
  document.getElementById('output').scrollTop = output.scrollHeight;
}
```

```css
#output{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

#typing-indicator{
  height: 15px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
<div id="typing-indicator"></div>
</div>
<input id="input"/>
<button id="send" onclick="send()">SEND</button>
```

I want `#typing-indicator` to be always at the bottom of `#output`
How can i do that with Pure JS or Jquery?
I need to inject  `<p/>` tags before the `#typing-indicator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try jQuery `.after()`

Instead of :

`` document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += `<p>${message}</p>`; ``

try:

`` $('#typing-indicator').after(`<p>${message}</p>`) ``

ref: http://api.jquery.com/after/

```js
function send(){
  var message = document.getElementById('input').value;
  $('#typing-indicator').after(`<p>${message}</p>`);
  $('#output').scrollTop();
}
```

```css
#output{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

#typing-indicator{
  height: 15px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script><div id="output">
<div id="typing-indicator"></div>
</div>
<input id="input"/>
<button id="send" onclick="send()">SEND</button>
```

Comment: I used jquery `.before()` but thanks for inspiration

Answer (score 1):

You can use [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) API to add the message before `typing-indicator` element.

```js
function send(){
  var message = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var messageElm = document.createElement('p');
  messageElm.innerHTML = message;
 
  var outputElm = document.getElementById('output');
  var indicatorElm = document.getElementById('typing-indicator');
  outputElm.insertBefore(messageElm, indicatorElm);
}
```

```css
#output{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

#typing-indicator{
  height: 15px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
<div id="typing-indicator"></div>
</div>
<input id="input"/>
<button id="send" onclick="send()">SEND</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

so you send function has to be as following

```
function send(){
var p = document.createElement("p");   // Create a <button> element
p.innerHTML = document.getElementById('input').value;;  
  document.getElementById('output').insertBefore(p,document.getElementById('typing-indicator')) ;
  document.getElementById('output').scrollTop = output.scrollHeight;
}
```

in this function you create you `p` element then inject it before `<div id="typing-indicator"></div>` element using `insertBefore` that inject element before another element 
you can check its documentation from the following [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp)

Comment: nope, i want to inject new message between the typing indicator and the last message

Answer (score 0):

Use a new container to save input messages and prepend new message to `innerHTML` when calling `send()`.

```js
function send(){
  var message = document.getElementById('input').value;
  document.getElementById('output-content').innerHTML = `<p>${message}</p>` + document.getElementById('output-content').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('output').scrollTop = output.scrollHeight;
}
```

```css
#output{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

#typing-indicator{
  height: 15px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
<div id="typing-indicator"></div>
<div id="output-content"></div>
</div>
<input id="input"/>
<button id="send" onclick="send()">SEND</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Flexbox you can have CSS do the work for you. Make `#output` a flexbox column container of 1:N rows and give child element `#typing-indicator` a lower order than the injected `<p>`'s.

Making `#typing-indicator` `order: 2` and the injected `<p>`'s `order: 1` will force them above `#typing-indicator` wherever and however you inject them...

The code:

```css
#output           { display: flex; flex-direction: column } /* column of 0:N rows */
#output>p         { order: 1 }
#typing-indicator { order: 2 }
/* has lower order than <p>'s and gets forced to the end of the FBL parent */
```

```html
<div id="output">
    <p>some injected &lt;p&gt;</p>
    <p>some injected &lt;p&gt;</p>
    <p>some injected &lt;p&gt;</p>
    <div id="typing-indicator">typing indicator</div>
    <p>some injected &lt;p&gt;</p>
    <p>some injected &lt;p&gt;</p>
    <p>some injected &lt;p&gt;</p>
    <p>some injected &lt;p&gt;</p>
</div>
<input id="input"/>
<button id="send" onclick="send()">SEND</button>
```

Comment: The first time around I forgot to check where the `#typing-indicator` went. Did not work properly, now it works as advertised... (No JQuery or JS, obviously)

Comment: FYI, because all `<p>` elements get the same `order` they will be layed out in document or injected order. (Writing a chat app, aren't you?)